# Frequent Functions: How to Structure?

Tags: c#

How should one structure their frequently used non-important functions (conversions, etc) in C# since everything must be contained in an object?  Usually I take all these functions and put them in a static Utility class.  Is this a good practice? How do most developers do it?

Comment: This reply isn't worthy of an actual "answer" but yeah, this is what I tend to do too. I don't see anything wrong with it; I'm not sure there's a design pattern for this which wouldn't be overkill for a generic method which I want to use in several different places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tends to be what most developers end up doing, myself included.

The only pitfall is when you start having a massive set utilities that shouldn't really all belong together (conversion, database access, logging you name it...).

Try to structure these as different assemblies, so projects that do not need a set of utilities will not have to import a large set of extraneous code.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant method for doing that in C# is using **extension methods** ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)). You can then only import the relevant namespace if you need your utility functions.

On the technical side this is basically just a static utility class as you described it, but in C# you get nice syntactic sugar for using them.

Comment: Not a down-vote, but the answer doesn't address the OP's question of how to structure their utility methods. Maybe you could provide some examples of how you structure your extension methods?

Comment: Sorry but I thought this is obvious when using extension methods. Each extension method extends the type that the utility method should be used with. Further structure is mostly irrelevant with extensions. Depending on the number you could arrange them one class per extended class or one class for all extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the particular need, I'll normally use a static structure or a registered service provider.  For example, for logging, I'll normally use a service provider and a logging class with an interface or base logger type, and then in dev mode I'll register a message box provider so that I can see all the logged lines for a particular log level, whereas for getting a particular List.find predicate for an object list I'll build a utility class that has a static method which returns a type-appropriate predicate class.

Answer (score 0):

I second the notion of using extension methods for this. I generally have classes, in a .Extensions namespace, like **StringExtensions**, **IEnumerableExtensions**, etc. Basically, I try and create a separate class for each logical grouping of functionality. Normally that means I group them by the type they extend, the type they produce, or the overarching feature they support (converting, formatting, etc).